# update html depending on time of day

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to update a greeting message at 6am, 12pm, and 6pm. I am looking for the most efficient way without polling the current time too frequently inside a loop.

```
setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    if(now.getHours() == 6 && now.getMinutes() == 0 && now.getSeconds() == 0){
        document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML = "Good Morning";
    } else if (now.getHours() == 12 && now.getMinutes() == 0 && now.getSeconds() == 0){
        document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML = "Good Afternoon";
    } else if (now.getHours() == 18 && now.getMinutes() == 0 && now.getSeconds() == 0){
        document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML = "Good Evening";
    }   
},3600000);
```

My immediate solution, shown above, was to poll the current time every hour. As you can imagine, there is a lot of wasted processing here to just update something 3 times in a 24 hour period. Furthermore, what if the page loads in the middle of the hour, then it will miss the update.

Comment: *there is a lot of wasted processing here* Where's this extra processing? An extremely small amount of code runs every hour? Is this slowing down your site somehow? For the rest, just stop checking minutes and seconds...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan so you are saying this is the best solution (minus the checks for minutes and seconds)?

Comment: Check for hour ranges rather than an absolute value, and yeah no need to check for minutes or seconds. Also run the code when the page loads (create a function that does this and reference the function in your `setInterval` call but also on page load).

Comment: There's this idea of "premature optimization" which you might be interested in :). Basically, it boils down to "if it ain't broke, don't fix it". You can add features like those mentioned by @Jasper and t.niese, but really, what you have (checking the hour only) is "good enough".

Comment: I wouldn't worry about "too much processing". Hardware can handle thousands of processes a minute. I don't think this will be a problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code could look something like that:

```
function updateTime() {
  var now = new Date();

  //display the greeting message base on the hour range
  if (now.getHours() >= 6 && now.getHours() < 12) {
    document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML = "Good Morning";
  } else if (now.getHours() > 12 && now.getHours() < 18) {
    document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML = "Good Afternoon";
  } else if (now.getHours() >= 18 || now.getHours() < 6) {
    document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML = "Good Evening";
  }

  //do the next check to the next full hour and 1 minute
  setTimeout(updateTime, (60 - now.getMinutes() + 1) * 60 * 1000);
}


updateTime();
```

The used cpu load that happens every hour is negligible.

Comment: setTimeout takes milliseconds, so 60 - 49 (49 minutes after the hour) * 60 (to get seconds) * 1000 (to get milliseconds) in order to find how many milliseconds until the next full hour.